# vision impairment as people age

Tags: nouns, postmodification

a. They claim they can prevent vision impairment as people grow older.

b. They claim they have found a solution for the issue of vision impairment as people get older.

Are the above sentences grammatically correct?

Here 'vision impairment as people grow older' is a single noun phrase designating a process (the gradual impairment of vision due to age.).

Comment: Yes

.

.

.

There's not much else to say.   Now what is your question that will take more than one word to answer?

Comment: Thank you so much. One word is enough for all of us!